# immutable collections implementation

Tags: java, collections, immutability

I have a general question with regards to immutable collections. I will use Java as a reference labguage as I know it best.

Firstly, is there a general approach to assuring immutability? By that I mean whether one should copy the entire collection, make changes and then return the new object? Is there any more complex, general approach?

Taking this a bit further, what about "obvious" (to me) mutable collections, such as trees? Usually they are implemented as Nodes with N children nodes. How would you assure immutability in this case? Clone and Copy all references recursively?

Following from the above, I was wondering whether what would be best approach to these collections:

1. List - array-based which we would copy before making changes?
2. Queues - two arrays for front and back, cloned before returning? What about bode based implementation?
3. Trees
4. Hashmap - copy the bucket array, as well as all collision lists?
5. Set

Thank you very much for your responses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Happily, much of this has already been done for you, check out [google guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) which has [ImmutableCollection](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableCollection.html), [ImmutableList](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html), [ImmutableSet](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet.html), [ImmutableMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html) etc etc.

Immutability is ensured by preventing subclasses of these classes (by either making them final, or making their constructors private).

When you make an immutable collection from a mutable one, the data in the mutable collection is copied, then all mutation operations are disallowed - they will throw an exception (`UnsupportedOperationException` for example).

For performance reasons, the guava libraries will do their best not to copy data if they don't need to.  For example, if you already have an `ImmutableMap`, and create a new one with `ImmutableMap.copyOf(theOtherImmutableMap)`, then no data is copied, since we already know the other map is immutable, it's ok to have two references to the same data.

Comment: But if you want immutable collections that can "pretend" to be changed instead of throwing an exception, check [PCollections](http://code.google.com/p/pcollections/). They will give a new collection on mutation operations, with minimal overhead.

Comment: Ok, thanks for pointing out the case of saving on copying in certain situatio. I have two questions though: if we make constructor private, do we instantiate collections from static methods? That kills testing a little bit. Furthermore, my question is, if I have a map, and I add next entry, immutable collection will returna pointer to a completely new collection. How? Copy all the data? How are other collections implemented. Thanks

Comment: @Bober02: How does using static methods to create immutable collections "kill testing"? As far as adding an entry to an immutable map, Guava's immutable collections simply don't allow you to do that. You can create a new immutable map using a builder to copy the original and add the new entry though. The PCollections do allow you to "add" an entry and get a new map. Finally, if you want to know about implementation, take a look at the source.

Comment: Agreed -- how does it kill testing?  Are you trying to mock collections themselves?  (Why?)  You might find [the Guava wiki](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained) useful here.

Comment: In terms of killing I thought of having to use static calls but I guess that depends on what you test etc. A more important thing is whether you use copying in the underlying implementations? Whether it is the builder or object itself, you need incorporate copying mechanism to ensure immutability right?

Comment: @Bober02: Static _state_ is a problem for testing, but not methods (provided they don't have side effects, etc.). Constructors aren't really any different than static factory methods in terms of testability. As far as copying: yes, Guava's immutable collections do copy where necessary to ensure immutability. Take a look at the source (example: [ImmutableList](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.java)) and you can see exactly what's done.

Comment: @colinD: thanks for your answer. So what you are trying to say is that static method calls within you tested objects are OK provided they are stateless and immutable? Also, does PCollections also use copying as a way of immutability? Thx

Comment: @Bober02: I'm basically saying that if using a constructor in your class to create an object is OK, using a static method to do the same thing is also OK. If you need to be able to provide a fake implementation of something, it should be passed in through the constructor. I'm not familiar with PCollections myself, but I'm sure it has to copy any mutable data structures that are passed to it to be added.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of Java the Collections utility class is your friend. Rather than do these operations manually I would suggest working through the API given. In particular look at the immutable and unmodifiable  methods.

For instance, in terms of immutable there is:

```
<T> List<T>
emptyList() 
          Returns the empty list (immutable).
static
<K,V> Map<K,V>
emptyMap() 
          Returns the empty map (immutable).
static
<T> Set<T>
emptySet() 
          Returns the empty set (immutable).
```

For unmodifiable you have:

```
static
<T> Collection<T>
unmodifiableCollection(Collection<? extends T> c) 
          Returns an unmodifiable view of the specified collection.
static
<T> List<T>
unmodifiableList(List<? extends T> list) 
          Returns an unmodifiable view of the specified list.
static
<K,V> Map<K,V>
unmodifiableMap(Map<? extends K,? extends V> m) 
          Returns an unmodifiable view of the specified map.
static
<T> Set<T>
unmodifiableSet(Set<? extends T> s) 
          Returns an unmodifiable view of the specified set.
static
<K,V> SortedMap<K,V>
unmodifiableSortedMap(SortedMap<K,? extends V> m) 
          Returns an unmodifiable view of the specified sorted map.
static
<T> SortedSet<T>
unmodifiableSortedSet(SortedSet<T> s)
```

There are others and some strategies you can implement underneath but I would start there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're intention is to understand how immutable collections work within the framework of functional languages (like haskell etc.). The idea being that all collections are immutable and final, thereby avoiding all the multi-threading gotchas with regards to mutability, synchronization etc., but still allow you to add and remove and modify as though they were mutable

The best examples I have seen for this have been in the source code for [Clojure](http://clojure.org/). It is a language that is lisp-like and therefore deals with immutable collections as a core feature. I would highly recommend looking at how collections are implememnted in clojure, as they are bound to answer many of your questions. Likely some things will be just too complicated (I still barely understand ***tries***). See [here](http://www.infoq.com/articles/in-depth-look-clojure-collections) and good luck

Comment: Why are they final? In order to prevent others from putting mutable methods on them?

Answer (score 0):

Clojure contains such immutable (or persistent) [collections](http://clojure.org/data_structures?responseToken=0920a89c78e77e630e53610649600c4ae).

It provides all the collections you are after, and supports mutation-via-construction:  Put simply, adding or removing new elements returns a new collection, which in general *does* reuse large parts of the old collection through clever use of Trie-type data structures.

On their own, these are a poor fit for using in straight Java - they're designed to use in Clojure.

[Pure4j](https://github.com/robmoffat/pure4j) is an attempt to port these (and the immutable/value based style advocated by Clojure) to the Java language.  It might be what you're after.

*Disclaimer: I am the developer of Pure4J*